# Is taking an idiom literally necessarly off topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

When I hear idioms like *"it's hard finding a needle in a haystack"*, *"you can't have too many lifeboats on a ship"*, or *"You can't teach an old dog new tricks"*, I sometimes wonder if it's actually true, instead of just repeating those phrases.

Is it (and if so, why) off topic to apply skepticism to the literal meaning of these claims ?

It is something that is often done on the show [Mythbusters](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TropesExaminedByTheMythBusters), for instance, and it is often very interesting.

Answer (score 4):

The idioms themselves are not necessarily notable claims, though some of them represent a commonly held belief. Of your three examples I would only regard the third one as enough to make a question out of it.

"You can't teach an old dog new tricks" represents the common belief that the older you get it gets harder to learn new things. I would regard that as a notable claim and I'm sure there are lots of studies about it.

You can certainly use the idiom as a starting point, but I wouldn't cling to the literal meaning of it. But some idioms can make good questions here.

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree that idioms and proverbs are fun and interesting. I also watch Mythbusters :-)

However, *are they notable claims?*

In other words: **does anyone claim that an idiom—*when taken literally*—is actually true?**

If so, the question is notable and acceptable.

If not, then the question is trivial, not notable and should be closed.

Bottom line: **Just because it's a proverb, it doesn't mean it's notable**.